# Listening for outside events. Bash to NodeJS bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

Being inside of a NodeJS process, how can I listen for events from bash?

For example

**NodeJS** side

```
obj.on("something", function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

**Bash** side

```
$ do-something 'Hello World'
```

Then in the NodeJS stdout will appear `"Hello World"` message.

How can I do this?

I guess it's related to [signal events](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#signal_Events).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with using signals is that you can't pass arguments and most of them are reserved for system use already (I think `SIGUSR2` is really the only safe one for node since `SIGUSR1` starts the debugger and those are the only two that are supposed to be for user-defined conditions).

Instead, the best way that I've found to do this is by using [UNIX sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket); they're designed for inter process communication.

The easiest way to setup a UNIX socket in node is by setting up a standard net server with [`net.createServer()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) and then simply passing a file path to [`server.listen()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_callback) to create the socket at the path you specified. ***Note:** It's important that a file at that path doesn't exist, otherwise you'll get a `EADDRINUSE` error.*

Something like this:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
    connection.on('data', function(data) {
        // data is a Buffer, so we'll .toString() it for this example
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});

// This creates a UNIX socket in the current directory named "nodejs_bridge.sock"
server.listen('nodejs_bridge.sock');

// Make sure we close the server when the process exits so the file it created is removed
process.on('exit', function() {
    server.close();
});

// Call process.exit() explicitly on ctl-c so that we actually get that event
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    process.exit();
});

// Resume stdin so that we don't just exit immediately
process.stdin.resume();
```

Then, to actually send something to that socket in bash, you can pipe to `nc` like this:

```
echo "Hello World" | nc -U nodejs_bridge.sock
```

Comment: +1, in case anyone is wondering how to output something, just `connection.write("foo\n");` inside data callback.

Comment: When I'm trying to execute `echo "Hello World" | nc -U nodejs_bridge.sock` from bash an error occurs `nc: unix connect failed: No such file or directory`. Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 7):

What about using FIFOs?

NodeJS code:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
  }
});
```

NodeJS startup (the `3>/tmp/...` is a trick to keep FIFO open):

```
mkfifo /tmp/nodeJsProcess.fifo
node myProgram.js </tmp/nodeJsProcess.fifo 3>/tmp/nodeJsProcess.fifo
```

Bash linkage:

```
echo Hello >/tmp/nodeJsProcess.fifo
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but I chose UNIX sockets. Voted you both. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The signals described in the page that you've linked are used to send some specific "command" to processes. This is called "Inter Process Communication". You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) a first definition of IPC.

You can instruct you node.js code to react to a specific signal, as in [this](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_signal_events) example:

```
// Start reading from stdin so we don't exit.
process.stdin.resume();

process.on('SIGUSR1', function() {
  console.log('Got SIGUSR1.  Here you can do something.');
});
```

Please note that the signal is sent to the process, and not to a specific object in the code.

If you need to communicate in a more specific way to the node.js daemon you can listen on another port too, and use it to receive (and eventually send) control commands.

Comment: And how to emit such an event?

Comment: In this case, in bash `kill -9 SIGUSR1`

Comment: @StefanoF I think you mean `kill -s SIGUSR1 <pid>`

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, the correct syntax is the one stated by @MikeS