# NodeJS usb module issue on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, usb

I've just tried to install usb module for node via npm on Ubuntu ([usb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb) and then [electron-usb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-usb)) but it doesn't work because of the version (look at [screenshot](https://ibb.co/g57noG)).

I've also installed `sudo apt-get install build-essential libudev-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev g++-multilib libudev-dev:i386` before module installation as written in the instructions.

How to make it work? Is there any other way to control usb ports with node?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and figured out that I can do the same with `udev` rules, so no usb module for node required. All you need to do is to listen bash commands from node as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411512/listening-for-outside-events-bash-to-nodejs-bridge), so that you can add custom rule in `rules.d/` folder and echo some data on any event and then make node listen to it. But this is a terrible way. 2017 and you can't just take control over usb ports with node out of the box, lol.